# phpmyadmin knows password to mysql db i've forgotten, can I extract it?

Tags: php, mysql

I put myself into a bit of a pickle.

I'm building a site for a client who is hosted on the most user-hostile ISP I've ever dealt with, but I won't name them 'cause that's not what this is about.

Anyway, with his account my client gets 1 (one!) MySQL database. Fortunately, I only need one for the CMS I'm setting up for him.

I set things up yesterday, including phpmyadmin, ran a short test to make sure I could log on from the site and create records, and that was that.

I go back today and have to provide the MySQL creds again, and it turns out I didn't properly record the username/password I used for the database. But phpmyadmin remembers it, because I can still access the db that way and make changes, just not from the web interface.

Is there any way I can extract that username/password info from phpmyadmin 4.0.5?

NOTE: I do not have root access to anything, it's not my server, and I don't have SSH access either.

Comment: How you are accessing the database. is the password is stored in your browser ?

Comment: Well, I go to phpmyadmin and log in. That password I have. phpmyadmin then opens up the database. So I assume the MySQL database password is stored in phpmyadmin somewhere. I need to be able to access the MySQL database from a different web interface, not phpmyadmin, and for that I need the credentials for MySQL, not just for phpmyadmin.

Comment: I think you need to enter the same login and password to connect

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Google Chrome / Chromium, you can use [this extension here](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAAahUKEwizmonRqbfHAhUBtxQKHcFzAdw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fhtml-revealer-and-passwor%2Ffgeopcldenngppapceagonnenonklpbn&ei=2prVVbPFJYHuUsHnheAN&usg=AFQjCNG_UgGValPvlTjX80S7dTXa2KFWYw&bvm=bv.99804247,d.bGg) to recover your password.

Comment: Thnk you for that, but that extension and others like it only show passwords on pages you actually enter them - they don't help in a case like mine where phpmyadmin has the creds stored and I never see them.

Comment: Okay, that's pretty bad I guess. I don't know if phpmyadmin stores the passwords in plain text (I hope not) but in your case, this will be be bad. Did you achieved something yet?